# Check if framework update is installed in wix project

Tags: .net, wix, installation, wix3.10

For the software house where I work I extend an Open Source IDE (SharpDevelop) with framework 4. I use VS2015 and I added NuGet package Microsoft.Bcl.Async to use async/await keywords.

But there is a problem. If in the user's PC is installed only framework 4.0 (not 4.5 or greater), needs to install fix KB2468871.

There is a way in wix project to detect if fix KB2468871 is installed? If there is a way, if not installed, can I install automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Wix project, but you try to run a another process for check the framework version and eventually install the fix.